# Create a dictionary from a nested structure (with arrays of other Structures) Swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, codable

I am using the Post method of Alamofire; so I need to create the parameters from an existing nested Model that contains arrays of other models
I was looking for a way to do but in vain, anyone can help, please!

I AM A BEGINNER IN SWIFT, PLEASE STOP UNRATING MY QUESTION

Like this example

```
struct Car: Codable{
var id :Int, 
var name:String, 
var users:[User],
..

 var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "id" : id,
            "name" : name,
            "users" : users,  XXX WRONG XXX
        ]
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time making the right format for the "users: [User]" field

```
struct User: Codable{
var id :Int, 
var name:String, 
var email:String,
..

 var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "id" : id,
            "name" : name,
            "email" : email,
        ]
    }
}
```

with this Wrong Format I am facing this error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'
```

Thank you,

Comment: Where is the part where you convert to JSON? Your use of Codable suggests you are going to use JSONEncoder, so where is the code where you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `map` it to the `dictionaryRepresentation` to make it work like this:

```
"users" : users.map { $0.dictionaryRepresentation }
```

A better approach would be to pass the `var car: Car` object since it already conforms to `Codable` Alamafire does the encoding for you, ie., you don't have to make the `dictionaryRepresentation` for passing it as the parameter in `Alamorire` request.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how can I use Alamofire for that ? when i use the jsonDecoder it gives me a variable of type Data not a dictionary, so i can't use it as the parameters

Comment: Did you mean json encoder? If so, you don't have to use it, just pass the object and alamofire will take care of the encoding as I've mentioned in my post.

Comment: I tried it but it gives me this error :
Cannot convert value of type 'Car' to expected argument type 'Parameters?' (aka 'Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>')

Comment: Add another post regarding this if you're still facing an issue, will try to figure out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Well, I solved the issue with the help of your answer, but I just wanted to know one more efficient way to do it using Alamofire (Because I didn't know about it )

Comment: Yeah, no harm in asking about it in another post. Post the link below and I'll try to take a look and help you out.

Comment: Thank you! I figure it out! it is actually way easier to use the default encoding of Alamofire!

Comment: Hello, @Frankenstein I am having a similar problem with Alamofire can you take a look at this question, please? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63627077/append-nested-data-as-in-parameters-of-multi-form-swift-alamofire]